# Format ggplot font sizes for printing on paper

Tags: r, plot, printing, formatting, cowplot

My goal is to generate plot in R so that it would print nicely on letter paper. Below is my example:

```
library(cowplot)

sample_df <- data.frame(col_1=c(1,2,3), col_2=c(6,7,8))
plot_1 <-ggplot(data=sample_df, aes(x = col_1, y =col_2, group=1))+
  geom_line()+ggtitle('Title 1')
plot_2 <-ggplot(data=sample_df, aes(x = col_1, y =col_2, group=1))+
  geom_line()+ggtitle('Title 2')

width_letter = 6
height_letter = width_letter*8.5/11

pdf('outpdf_1.pdf', width=width_letter, height=height_letter)
plot_grid(plot_1, plot_2, labels = "AUTO", ncol = 2, align = 'v', scale = 0.65) +   
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2,2,2,2), "cm")) 

dev.off()
```

It generates ugly plot, I seem not be able to find a way to format plot nicely i.e. resize axis and fonts. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: @d.b. I tried it, it does not help, same output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right after `library(cowplot)` run the following code: `theme_set(theme_cowplot(font_size=8))`. The default font size for `theme_cowplot()` (the ggplot theme that becomes the default when you load the `cowplot` package) is 14. Changing this to a lower value will reduce the font sizes in your plots. You can also change individual font sizes for various plot elements (e.g., axis labels, plot title, etc.) with `theme` statements when you create each plot.

Here's what the PDF file looks like with the smaller font size:

[image]

As another option, when you open the PDF device, you can use a multiple of the height and width values you created. For example: `pdf('outpdf_1.pdf', width=width_letter*2, height=height_letter*2)`. This will result in text that is smaller, relative to the plot area, but the plot will still be rendered within a single page in the PDF file. I prefer the first method, but you can go with this approach also.

To respond to your comment: ggplot's default theme is `theme_grey` (run `?theme_grey` to see the setting for this and other available themes). You can see that each theme has a `base_size` with a default setting. All the of the font sizes for labels and titles are scaled relative to the `base_size`. You can see all the various setting for each theme by typing its name in the console. For example, run `theme_grey`.

When I first started using cowplot, I noticed that when you load it, it defaults to a new theme, `theme_cowplot`. Type `?theme_cowplot` to see its help file and `theme_cowplot` to see all the settings. You'll notice that unlike the default ggplot themes, `theme_cowplot` creates a new argument, `font_size`, which plays the same role as `base_size` in ggplot's default themes. Looking over the output of `theme_cowplot` you can see that it starts with `theme_grey(base_size=font_size, ...)`.

More generally, you can always start with some theme, cowplot, grey, classic, etc., modify the overall font scaling with `base_size` (or `font_size` in `theme_cowplot`) and then change individual fonts with a `theme` statement. You can also store these changes in a new theme object that you can then apply to any plot, so that you don't have to repeat all the theme elements with each new plot. There's also a `ggthemes` package that has additional pre-packaged themes.

Comment: Thanks very much. How did you find this solution?

Comment: Thank you so much for yout help. It really help me in my research plots.